# USB C cable with two red wires instead of one red and one black one

Tags: usb, cables, wire, usb-c

I need to deep flash my phone, however instead of the normal red, black, white and green wires, my cable has two red, one white, one green and two uncoated wires. Since I don't really wanna die, which cables should I short out without giving myself an electric shock? (which cables are data+ and ground?)

Comment: This question does not meet the quality requirements of this SE.  I can see that you have not read the Tour page (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).  Please do so and revise your question.

Comment: What do you mean under "deep flash" your phone? Do you mean to discharge your phone battery down to 0% charge status?

Answer (score 1):

Is your USB like this? [image]

If so, i would recommend using a multimeter to find which cable belongs to every pin. Then:

~A6 & B6 is the standard Green cable

~A7 & B7 is the White cable,

~A1 & B1 & A12 & B12 is the black, and

~A4 & B4 & A9 & B9 is the red cable,

which can be used as a "USB A" based on the picture bellow.

[image]

*Even if you flip it, you will get the same cables.